# how to put observablecollection in List

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

i want to put current observablecollection data in list on button click event. bellow is c# code but it gives error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    ObservableCollection<CheckInData> _CheckInCollection = new ObservableCollection<CheckInData>();


    public ObservableCollection<CheckInData> CheckInCollection
    {
        get { return _CheckInCollection; }
    }

    public class CheckInData
    {
        public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Currecny { get; set; }
        public decimal Discount { get; set; }
        public string CheckOut { get; set; }
        public int TotalDay { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public int CheckOutYear { get; set; }
        public int CheckOutMonth { get; set; }
        public int CheckOutDay { get; set; }
        public Boolean IncToday { get; set; }
    }

    private void btnPrintInvoice_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataToExcel.Invoice inv = new DataToExcel.Invoice();
        inv._BilledTo = Guest[0];

        foreach (CheckInData coll in _CheckInCollection)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < _CheckInCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                inv._RoomPrice.Add(coll.RoomNumber[i].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What line does it give you that exception on?

Comment: inv._RoomPrice.Add(coll.RoomNumber[i].ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like inv._RoomPrice or coll.RoomNumber is null.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint on the line that's throwing the exception and inspect each variable that can be null:  inv, inv._RoomPrice, coll, coll.RoomNumber

Once you find it, determine where you think it's supposed to be initialized and fix the bug that's causing it not be initialized.